# How should I display values from few arrays in my custom Adapter for ListActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout

For example I have such code:

```
    String[] values = new String[] { "Text1", "Text2", "Text3",
            "Text4", "Text5", "Text6", "Text7", "Text8",
            "Text9", "Text10" };
    String[] subvalues = new String[] {"subtext1", "subtext2", "subtext3", "subtext4", 
            "subtext5", "subtext6", "subtext7", "subtext8", "subtext9", "subtext10"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.rawlayout,
            R.id.phone_number,
            values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This sample fills TextView R.id.phone_number with the values from the values array. However I have an other textView R.id.date_time and I want to fill it with the values from the subvalues array.

How should I modify my code to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1):

You can either combine your two Array into a `List<Map<String, String>>` and use a [SimpleAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) to display both values. Or you can create a custom Adapter that takes both of your Arrays and displays them appropriately.

I recommend using a custom Adapter, because SimpleAdapters are slower than customized code. If you have never created a custom Adapter there are a few Google I/O presentations by lead Android developers dedicated to this subject, like [Turbo-Charge Your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html).

Comment: Or create a class (a POJO) which stores the data.

Comment: Yes, you can create a new object that holds both values and store them in a List, much like `List<Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: I was just making a suggestion to add to your answer. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: No offense taken! It is a good suggestion, since a `Map` extra features that aren't necessary here. A custom class should be faster for the author's example.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I modificate my code to achieve my objective?

You can always use [Cursor Joiner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html) Witch allows to join multiple lists/cursors in to a a single cursor. 
When you have that create cursor adapter class(allows for custom layouts) witch you assign as adapter to your listView.

```
CursorJoiner joiner = new CursorJoiner(cursor1, projection1, cursor2, projection2);


for (CursorJoiner.Result joinerResult : joiner) {
    switch (joinerResult) {

    case LEFT: // handle case where a row in cursorA is unique


        Log.d(tag, "left");

        break;
    case RIGHT: // handle case where a row in cursorB is unique

        Log.d(tag, "right");
        break;
    case BOTH: // handle case where a row with the same key is in
           // both // cursors
        Log.d(tag, "both");
        break;
    }
```

You can also use a [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html)

Comment: How do you use a CursorJoiner with primitive Arrays? I have never tried this.

Comment: @sam look for MatrixCursor